Annihilator method for solving systems of ODEs
According to Chapter 6 of the book titled "Fundamentals of Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems" writen by Nagel, Saff and Snider, the classical "method of undetermined coefficients" for solving nonhomogeneous ODEs can be made rigoros by introducing the notion of "annihilators". In Chapter 9 of this book, the authors also talked about the use of the "method of undetermined coefficients" for solving systems of nonhomogeneous ODEs. This is just an extension of the same method for solving single ODEs. I wonder if the notion of "annihilators" can also be extended to systems of ODEs.

Yes - in fact, the text by Zill has a section on it.
